# Producing a field with $7^3$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Producing a field with $7^3=343$ elements.

Okay, so if I can find an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Z_7$ of degree $3$ then I'll have done it.

Now, since it's of degree $3$ all I have to do is check for linear factors by finding a degree $3$ polynomial with no roots. I could just guess and check, but I was wondering if there was a more methodical way to do this, perhaps there is an insight that I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Kummer extension?

Comment: Nah I'm supposed to do it this way by finding an irreducible polynomial >.<

Comment: Related [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244288/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2649677/11619). Not gonna use my dupehammer. Only gonna make the calculus rep farmers look better.

Comment: Yes, still worth to read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649677/constructing-a-finite-field-of-order-343?noredirect=1&lq=1) in this context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$x^3\equiv\pm1\bmod7$ for all $x\in\{1,\dots,6\}$. We thus choose $x^3+2$ as the irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Probably simplest.

Comment: I'd choose $x^3-2$.

Comment: brilliant! I never think about stuff like this, thanks!

Comment: This only works for $n=3$, no? If the exponent were $4$, we couldn't conclude that $x^4=a$ is irreducible from the fact that $a$ has no fourth root in the ground field.

Comment: @JackM This wouldn't work for $7^4$ elements because you'd also have to check that the candidate polynomial doesn't split into irreducible quadratics. Indeed.

Comment: Does this also follow from fermats little theorem? $x^6=1$ mod 7 so $x^3$ must be $1$ or $-1$? Or is that not true, that we can have other self inverse elements? Obviously you can, right?

Comment: @MichaelVaughan It would follow from FLT, yes.